# Enable/disable nvidia Optimus programmatically using C++ under Ubuntu amd64

Tags: c++, ubuntu, opengl, opencl, optimus

**EDIT**: This is imo not an exact duplicate, because this question is for a solution **spesific to Ubuntu**, while the other is for a **cross-platform solution**.

In order to save power it is common in recent graphics architectures to dynamically switch between a discrete high-performance and an integrated lower-performance GPU, where the high-performance GPU is only enabled when the need for extra performance is present.

This technology is branded as [Optimus](http://www.nvidia.com/object/optimus_technology.html) for nvidia GPUs.

However due to the non-standardized way in which these technologies work, managing them from a developer's perspective can be a nightmare. For example in [this PDF](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/devzone/devcenter/gamegraphics/files/OptimusRenderingPolicies.pdf) from nvidia on the subject, they explain the many intricacies, limitations and pitfalls that you will have to worry about as a developer to manage nvidia Optimus on just one platform.

As an example, in the linked PDF above, the following is a tip for selecting GPU on Windows:

```
extern "C" {
 _declspec(dllexport) DWORD NvOptimusEnablement = 0x00000001;
}
```

However that will only work on Windows platform. What would be the equivalent under Ubuntu?

I am especially interrested in how I can make this work reliably with OpenCL and OpenGL (interop), as that is the intended goal of my project. I am working with C++14/Qt5.7/OpenCL/OpenGL codebase under Ubuntu 16.04-amd64 using nvidia hardware (closed source driver v367).

Comment: Sorry, should have mentioned, I am on closed version 367

Comment: I updated question, but really from developer perspective I would want this to work for both closed and open driver.

Comment: Did you try putting heavy opencl stress(like a sgemm) on first device and at the same time check for new platforms or devices(gpus) appeared or not?

Comment: huseyin: no, will that have any effect?

Comment: no, just a guessed as if implementation checks registry for platforms or devices and registry is altered by optimus when idle or under load.